# Can Playwright handle OAUTH 2.0 logons that use redirects

Tags: playwright

I am trying figure out how to use playwright to logon to our web application and get an access token that provides access to web services. It uses oauth 2.0 redirects with grant type Authorization Code Flow with PKCE. The response content isn't available after the final user/password logon. Webdriver works fine and has the access token available after user/password logon. I'm trying to replicate the same process in Playwright.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are asking if Playwright can be used to login to an application using OAuth, which obviously has redirects happening.

Official docs about Playwright authentication: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth

Example OAuth login that works just fine:

```
test.describe('Login with OAuth', () => {
    test("login, save cookies and localStorage", async ({ page, context }) => {
        // Navigate to application login page
        await page.goto('https://loginwithoauth.com');

        // Log in by clicking the OAuth button
        await page.locator('text=OAuth login').click();

        // Now we are moving to a 3rd party login page....

        // We are at a new page for login, type email address
        await page.click('[placeholder="Email Address"]');
        await page.locator('[placeholder="Email Address"]').fill('username...');
        await page.click('[placeholder="Password"]');
        await page.locator('[placeholder="Password"]').fill('password...');
        await page.locator('button:has-text("Sign in")').click();
        
        // Now we're back to our own app
        // Wait that the main page has loaded
        await page.waitForURL('**/home', { timeout: 10000 });

        // Wait for network to be idle, if we save storage too early, needed storage values might not yet be available
        await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');

        // Save cookies and localstorage to a file, which we can use later in the tests to be logged in automatically
        await context.storageState({ path: 'state.json' });
        console.log('Cookies and localStorage should now be saved in state.json file for further cache usage...');
    });
    // Test suite ends
});
```

Comment: My problem was hard to explain. This solution works as expected where we log onto a real web application and I could internal access tokens from localstorage. However my problem was trying to generate these tokens using a redirect page that doesn't exist. It seems Playwright isn't able to do this fake logon. It thinks the URL is chrome-error://chromewebdata/ and can't get the internal access tokens.

Comment: Yes sorry I have to admit I'm not quite following your workflow :) but just to add some ideas: you can always run API calls in Playwright to get tokens if an API exists, or you can store manually tokens in cookies or localStorage or as variables in code that you can access later. I think if you need further help you should really add all the details and workflows, examples in your original question post.